# Callbacks are not getting called when using concurrent tasks in gearman

Tags: concurrency, task, gearman

I did check the example reverse_client_cb with the reverse_worker as a worker.
The worker is getting called and executed but not a single callback ( complete,fail,etc) is getting called in the client.

Below is a sample worker and client that I wrote to check the same, but, same problem.
Is there any configuration that's need to be done in gearman or in the way the worker and clients are executed?

## sampleworker.cc

```
void* myfunc(gearman_job_st *job, void *data,size_t *size,gearman_return_t *ret)
{
    printf("\nmyfunc called\n");

    *ret=GEARMAN_SUCCESS;
    char *result=(char*)calloc(30,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(result,"work completed");
    *size=30;
    return result;
}

int main(int args,char* argv[])
{
   gearman_worker_st worker;

   gearman_worker_create(&worker);
   gearman_worker_add_server(&worker,"localhost",0);

   gearman_return_t ret =     gearman_worker_add_function(&worker,"sample",0,myfunc,NULL);

   while(1) gearman_worker_work(&worker);

   gearman_worker_free(&worker);
   return 0;
}
```

## sampleclient.cc

```
static gearman_return_t complete(gearman_task_st *task)
{
     printf("Completed: %s %.*s\n", gearman_task_job_handle(task),
     (int)gearman_task_data_size(task), (char *)gearman_task_data(task));
     return GEARMAN_SUCCESS;
}

static gearman_return_t fail(gearman_task_st *task)
{
    printf("Failed: %s\n", gearman_task_job_handle(task));
    return GEARMAN_SUCCESS;
}

 int main(int args,char* argv[])
{
        gearman_client_st client;
    gearman_return_t ret;

    gearman_client_create(&client);
    gearman_client_add_server(&client,"localhost",0);

    gearman_task_st task,*task2;
    gearman_client_add_task(&client,&task,NULL,"sample",NULL,argv[1],(size_t)strlen(argv[1]),&ret);

    gearman_client_set_complete_fn(&client, &complete);
    gearman_client_set_fail_fn(&client, &fail);

    gearman_client_run_tasks(&client);  

    gearman_client_free(&client);
    return 0;
  }
```

## usage

```
./sampleworker
./sampleclient Hello
```

"myfunc called" getting printed and the client is also waiting till the worker completes the job. But nothing is printed from complete or fail functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

I removed the following libs which was installed and now I'm getting all the callbacks.

> libgearman-client-async-perl - Asynchronous client for gearman distributed job system
>
> libgearman-client-perl - Client for gearman distributed job system.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion. your made some mistake in function invoking sequence.

```
gearman_client_set_complete_fn(&client, &complete);
gearman_client_set_fail_fn(&client, &fail);
```

// the function must be called after set_complete_fn

```
gearman_client_add_task 
gearman_client_run_tasks(&client);
```